# Доступ к связанным моделям в django

Tags: python, django

Имеется три модели

- набор типовых мероприятий
- фото к мероприятию в наборе
- мероприятия

```
class EventsStack(models.Model):
    """Набор мероприятий(заготовок)"""
    name = models.CharField("Название мероприятия", max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField("Описание мероприятия")
```

```
class EventsPhoto(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Заголовок", max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField("Описание")
    image = models.ImageField("Изображение", upload_to="events_photo/")
    event = models.ForeignKey(EventsStack, related_name='images', verbose_name="Мероприятие", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
class Events(models.Model):
    """События/мероприятия"""
    type = models.ForeignKey(EventsStack, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name="event_type_id", null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField("Дата и время")
```

В `views.py` выделяю мероприятия так: `events = Events.objects.filter(date__gte = date.today())[0:12]`

**Как мне в шаблонизаторе вставить соответсвующие картинки?**

Мне видится, что надо идти по логике `Events->EventsStack->EventsPhoto`

Шаблонизатор:

```
{% for event in events %}
                <div class="event-block">
                        <div class="event-header">
                            <p class="event-title">
                                {{ event.type.name }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    <div class="event-image-block">
                        {% for photo in ?????? %}
                            <img src="{{ photo.image.url }}" alt="{{ photo.title }}" class="event-image">
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете обратиться к `EventsPhoto` через [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

***Пример:***

```py
{% for photo in event.type.images.all %}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо